# Rails jQuery mobile not working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

I have built a Rails 4 jQuery mobile app which works fine in development. The app works in production but not the jQuery Mobile stuff. I just get un-styled output. I am using the gems for jQuery and jQuery mobile. My platform is Ubuntu 13.04 on Rackspace, Ruby 2.0.0-p195, Rails 4.0-rc1, postgresql, Nginx, Unicorn.

Gemfile

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery_mobile_rails'
```

application.js

```
//   
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.mobile
//= require turbolinks
//= require clubapp
//= require_tree .
```

application.css

```
*
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*= require jquery.mobile
*= require clubapp
*/
```

layout

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

Comment: What is your version of jquery-rails? The current version does not include jquery-ui. If you did not specify the version number in your gemfile your production and development machine might be using two different versions. Specify `jquery-rails, '2.3.0'` in your gemfile and see if that works because that version still includes jquery-ui.

Comment: jquery-rails (3.0.0)
    jquery_mobile_rails (1.3.0)

Comment: Is both development and production using the same version?

Comment: Yes, I made the change to 2.3.0 but it made no difference

Comment: Changed the jQuery Rails gem back to specify no version and after a reboot its now working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to reboot the server. Now this works fine.